# plot - adding text to residual plots to identify potential outliers in R

Tags: r, plot, survival

I have created residual plots using the `plot` function in R:

```
# residual diagnostics
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
fitresi<-residuals(fit_crm,type="martingale")
fitpred<-predict(fit_crm)
plot(fitresi,ylab="residuals")
plot(fitpred,fitresi,xlab="prediction",ylab="residuals")
lines(lowess(fitpred,fitresi))
plot(BurnData$inf.time,fitresi,xlab="expression",ylab="residuals")
lines(lowess(BurnData$inf.time,fitresi))
plot(BurnData$inf.time,xlab="TNM",ylab="residuals")
lines(lowess(BurnData$inf.time,fitresi))
```

[image]

However I cannot figure out how too add text to the outlying observations. For example in the upper left plot, there seems to be an outlier around inder 60-70. The are also some potential outliers in the other plots.

**How can i the ID to those observations?**  My data has the following structure:

```
> head(BurnData)
  Treatment Gender Race Surface head buttock trunk up.leg low.leg resp.tract type ex.time excision antib.time antibiotic inf.time infection
1         0      0    0      15    0       0     1      1       0          0    2      12        0         12          0       12         0
2         0      0    1      20    0       0     1      0       0          0    4       9        0          9          0        9         0
3         0      0    1      15    0       0     0      1       1          0    2      13        0         13          0        7         1
4         0      0    0      20    1       0     1      0       0          0    2      11        1         29          0       29         0
5         0      0    1      70    1       1     1      1       0          0    2      28        1         31          0        4         1
6         0      0    1      20    1       0     1      0       0          0    4      11        0         11          0        8         1
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
```

Comment: Since you are using base graphics you should be looking at `?identify`